# Maslow quote about the student questioning the teacher

Tags: reference-request, education

Maslow has a quote that i cannot find...  perhaps someone can assist.

in general he spoke that a student that questions the teacher is often called a troublemaker (of course paraphrased)

Does anyone actually know of this quote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The really bright student, the eager questioner, the probing searcher, especially if he is brighter than his teacher, is too often seen as a "wise guy," a threat to discipline, a challenger of his teacher's authority.  – Abraham Maslow, Toward a Psychology of Being, p. 74